# Python selenium loop over table just get first row

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using Selenium in Python to extract information from each row in a table. I have been able to successfully extract the id title for each row, which is what I need. However, I now need to read a specific cell for each row and retrieve its text. Here is the code I am using:

```
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel panel-primary']//table[@id='SheetDetails']")
body = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")

rows = body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

for i in range(len(rows)):
    
  
    numExpedicion = rows[i].get_attribute('id')
    numExpedicion = numExpedicion.split('-',1)[1]
    
    origenPlaza = rows[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@data-bind='text: CodPlaceOrg']")
    print(origenPlaza.text)
    
driver.quit()
```

I am getting the expected value for the numExpedicion variable. However, I am encountering an issue with the origenPlaza variable, as I am getting the same text for every row, which corresponds to the first row. My understanding is that it should look inside each row (tr) and find the text in that specific XPath. I am unsure why this is not happening.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does rows print? Does it only contain the first row or does it have the other rows?

Comment: Also, not really related to the question but you could loop over the rows instead of indexing them. `for row in rows:` instead of `for i in range(len(rows)):`

Comment: When I print any attribute for each row, It corresponds correctly for each row of the table,  I think the error is in the line:

 origenPlaza = rows[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@data-bind='text: CodPlaceOrg']")

like if it is taking the whole body and always taking the first row, but I put rows[i] first, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote in the comments, the problem is the xpath of `origenPlaza`.

```
origenPlaza = rows[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@data-bind='text: CodPlaceOrg']")
```

Since yu are using `rows[i]` as root, you have to add a dot `.` at the beginning of the xpath

```
.//td[@data-bind='text: CodPlaceOrg']
```

Moreover, notice that

```
.// selects any descendant node of the current node
./  selects a node which is a direct child of the current
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you solved me a lot of errors and problems I had with XPATHS. It worked fine.